# Why is mapStateToProps preventing props array from rendering correctly?

Tags: reactjs, redux

So basically there is something that could be done pretty easily with Vanilla React, I think, by just passing props directly to a child component. Here I did the same with Redux, and for some reason prop array won't be rendered correctly. It's a very small component. In its parent the array is appended every time a person presses 'Enter' adding a tag to the array of tags. They should then map onto the div, but it's not happening. Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong here.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './index.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    console.log(state.pertinentVariableArray)
    return { pertinentVariableArray:state.pertinentVariableArray };
}

class TagPanneau extends Component {

    render(){
        return(
            <div id="tagPanneauItself">
                {
                this.props.pertinentVariableArray.map((element,index)=>
                    <div className="tagElement" key={index}>{element}</div>
                )
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const ActualTagPanneau = connect(mapStateToProps)(TagPanneau);
export default ActualTagPanneau;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, if someone encounters a similar issue. It basically happened, because I tried to pass a copy of the array with an element appended to it to the reducer, instead of using immutability patterns of Redux such as using spread operation [...state.array,action.payload] basically dispatching an action with the value itself not pushing anything to the array in the component.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check this.props.pertinentVariableArr before using map. Beacause If pertinentVariableArr can `undefined`.
Suggest:

```
{
  this.props.pertinentVariableArray&& 
  this.props.pertinentVariableArray.map((element,index)=>
       <div className="tagElement" key={index}>{element}</div>)
}
```